# Expo AV Audio not audible on ios

Tags: ios, react-native, audio, expo, expo-av

Hi everyone I am using Expo AV to play sounds in my React Native (Expo-managed) app, the audio plays well and audibly on android but it doesn't play loudly and audibly on ios, and apple also rejected the app on App Store because of this

they said

> Your app declares support for audio in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist but did not include features that require persistent audio.
> Next Steps
> The audio key is intended for use by apps that provide audible content to the user while in the background, such as music player or streaming audio apps. Please revise your app to provide audible content to the user while the app is in the background or remove the "audio" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key.

and this is the expo-av audio mode settings

```js
Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        staysActiveInBackground: true,
        shouldDuckAndroid: true,
        interruptionModeIOS: 1,
        interruptionModeAndroid: 1,
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: false,
})
```

and I play the audio like so

```js
const {sound} = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
          {uri: audioURI},
          {
            shouldPlay: true,
          }
        );
```

and this is the import statement

```js
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
```

and I don't know if it was caused by the [React Native Music Control](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-music-control) library I am using for the Music control in the app

imported like

```js
import MusicControl from 'react-native-music-control'
```

and I call it immediately after playing the audio

```js
MusicControl.setNowPlaying({
            title: currentAudio.title,
            artwork: currentAudio.imageUrl, // URL or RN's image require()
            artist: currentAudio.artist,
            genre: currentAudio.genre,
            duration: (minutesToMilliseconds(currentAudio.playtime) / 1000), // (Seconds)
            description: currentAudio.description, // Android Only
            color: 0xffffff, // Android Only - Notification Color
            colorized: true, // Android 8+ Only - Notification Color extracted from the artwork. Set to false to use the color property instead
            isLiveStream: false, // iOS Only (Boolean), Show or hide Live Indicator instead of seekbar on lock screen for live streams. Default value is false.
        })
```

please what I'm I doing wrong, thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it

How?

I think it was the `react-native-music-control` that was causing it, I did the configuration of Expo AV Audio and `react-native-music-control` in a function and called the function in a React.useLayoutEffect in one of the main files of the app

but I discovered that if I changed something in the function, the audio get audible

so what I did was to call the function after calling `Audio.Sound.createAsync(...)`

```js
const {sound} = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
 { uri: audioDetails.url, },
           {
             shouldPlay: true,
           },
           (status: AVPlaybackStatus) => 
           onPlaybackStatusUpdate(...),
           false
          
         );
       useAppGlobalContextIn.initializeMusicControl() // the function where I called the Expo AV Audio and the MusicControl setup
```

the function

```js
const initializeMusicControl = React.useCallback(() => {
MusicControl.setCustomNotificationIcon(require('./assets/icon.png'))
MusicControl.enableBackgroundMode(true);
MusicControl.handleAudioInterruptions(true);
    // // // Basic Controls
MusicControl.enableControl('play', true)
MusicControl.enableControl('pause', true)
MusicControl.enableControl('stop', true)
MusicControl.enableControl('nextTrack', true)
MusicControl.enableControl('previousTrack', true)

    // // // Changing track position on lockscreen
MusicControl.enableControl('changePlaybackPosition', true)

    // // Seeking
MusicControl.enableControl('seekForward', false) // iOS only
MusicControl.enableControl('seekBackward', false) // iOS only
MusicControl.enableControl('skipForward', false)
MusicControl.enableControl('skipBackward', false)
    
    // // Android Specific Options
MusicControl.enableControl('seek', true) // Android only
MusicControl.enableControl('setRating', false)
MusicControl.enableControl('volume', true) // Only affected when remoteVolume is enabled
MusicControl.enableControl('remoteVolume', true)
 MusicControl.enableControl('closeNotification', true, { when: 'always' })



    // // // iOS Specific Options
MusicControl.enableControl('enableLanguageOption', false)
MusicControl.enableControl('disableLanguageOption', false)

Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
     staysActiveInBackground: true,
     shouldDuckAndroid: true,
     interruptionModeIOS: 1,
     interruptionModeAndroid: 1,
     allowsRecordingIOS: true,
     playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
 })
}, [])
```

then I called it like so

```js
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
initializeMusicControl()
}, [])
```

it kind of tricky, but when I ran across another issue with Expo AV Audio, I decided to change to [react-native-track-player](https://react-native-track-player.js.org/) and it works perfectly, it handles both the function of Expo AV Audio and `react-native-music-control` and also provides incredible events to work with remote events